# High-on opto-isolated relay schematic (5 V GPIO drive 24 V relay)

Tags: transistors, relay, bjt

[image: Schematic Snippet]

- 470R resistors between PCA9698 output port & LED (D2)

For this relay control circuit, I searched a lot of sample schematics before and picked this one to fit my application needs: HIGH-ON, Opto isolated & drive 24 V relay ([HF41F/24-ZST](https://assets.alliedelec.com/v1613646592/Datasheets/8abd44e47e1e11b113c931c697711149.pdf)).

I realized it should work but after I got the PCB & soldered it, it's not working.
After I sent 5 V high from PCA9698, the voltage between A1 & A2 is still 0 & it looks like 2N5551 isn't working like I think.

First, I thought the opto was broken so I removed R1 to make sure the opto worked fine. I could measure 24 V between Point-15 & 24GND by multimeter after send ON.

Second I thought about the transistor. I changed to few new 2N5551s & even used a S8050 to replace it. Still no luck.

I googled a lot of similar schematics but I still can't figure out what's wrong with it. Please provide me some hints or direction to solve this.

Comment: What is the voltage at the base of the transistor (pin 2)?

Comment: 10.06v (pin 2 & 24GND). weird?

Comment: Your transistor may not be installed correctly. 10 V from base to emitter would destroy the transistor (or indicate a destroyed one) because it the base-emitter voltage should never be > ~0.7 V.

Comment: You've not got a series resistor for your D2 and IRLED. Are you driving it directly from a PCA9698 port without a current limiting resistor?

Comment: So I need to change R1 to lager on like 10k or 15k,right? Or It’s a totally wrong circuits?

Comment: Please can you edit this information (and any other new info) into your question's schematic, rather than post it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece the full question together.

Answer (score 0):

The input current can be measured by the voltage drop across each resistor I=V/R

My guess is your Blue LED is preventing normal operation with the 470R added in text to your question.

My guestimate is;

5V-3.2V(Blue)-1.2(IR)=0.6 V  , PCA Driver ~ 50 Ohms + 470R = 520 ohms.  Thus Iin=0.6/520 = 1.1 mA which is not enough to drive 22 mA to the 1k Opto output to Vbe=0.7.

Opto CTR = 50% min

Choices:  1) Bypass Blue LED then 5-1.3V =3.7V  with 22mA Opto out and choose 15 mA LED drive current  gives sufficient margin

1. thus 3.7V/15 mA Change 470R to 240 or 250 R and bypass the BLUE LED.
2. Bypass 470R then with Blue LED using 15 mA assuming 3.0V  and IR LED = 1.3V  the voltage from 50 ohm driver may drop 75mV .  5V-3V-1.3V=~ 0.7V drop from 50 Ohm driver is now 10 mA, Which is not enough reach 15 mA even with 470R shorted out.

Option 1) is better. If you wanted to see the BLUE LED is should have it's own 470 R current limiting resistor from the driver to LED in parallel not series  and LED cathode to ground.

[image]